# How to update multiple table fields using data from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table users_grade

```
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |id |    name     |  grade_1   |   grade_2   |   grade_3    |
     | 1 |    John     |      A     |       A     |       B      |
     | 2 |    Paul     |      B     |       A     |       A      |
     | 3 |   George    |      B     |       A     |       A      |   
     | 4 |  Richard    |      A     |       B     |       A      |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I have to update users.grade table with old data from table.grades:

```
    table.grades

    +------------------------------------------------------+
    |ID |user_id  | grade_1   |   grade_2   |   grade_3    |
    |67 |     1   |      A    |       A     |       B      |
    |68 |     2   |      B    |       A     |       A      |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
```

How to update my table users_grade dumping the table.grades data? I have over 10K users.

Comment: 1. See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: What do you mean by *update* here?

Comment: That is a very very very basic question. The answer is really literally on the first page about `update` in the official MySQL documentation. Since I assume you definitely looked that up (that being easier than posting this question here), I'd assume an answer to this question would require great broadness, effectively explaining all basic of relational databases.

Comment: I know is not a spreadsheet, but the PHP is ready and gets the data from table users.grades. I looked up in other SO posts but i could´t find a asnwer to solve my question.

Comment: Are you asking how to move the data from table.grades to table.users_grade? Or are you asking how you can update data in table.users_grade with data in table.grades?

Answer (score 0):

this is basic mysql join update.

```
update user_grade u inner join table.grades g
    on u.id = g.user_id
    set
    u.grade_1 = g.grade_1, 
    u.grade_2 = g.grade_2, 
    u.grade_3 = g.grade_3
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html